# Dual boot AppCenter not working

Tags: appcenter

I'm on dual booth with Windows 7, and AppCenter does not update or install anything; it just hangs on "waiting in queue". There is a working Internet connection, and I have another non-dual boot PC where AppCenter works just fine. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm on dual boot (UEFI) with Windows10 and AppCenter installs work fine here (Installed a fresh copy yesterday)

There was an issue with the appcenter not so long ago ([issue description](https://medium.com/elementaryos/important-update-released-501c9d9f28b)) so you can follow these instructions.

Have you updated the OS

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Can you install via apt or apt-get? 
-------------------------------------------------17/05/17
UPDATE:
I run the upgrades and the appCenter is still working